# Difference between function and method?

Tags: terminology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [method vs function vs procedure vs class ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036330/method-vs-function-vs-procedure-vs-class)

Can some one give the differences between a method and a function?

Comment: i suggest you to read at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function?rq=1).
1) A **function** is a piece of code that is called by name
2) a **method** is a piece of code that is called by a name that is associated with an object. to it is implicitly passed the object on which it was called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are the same. Both are subroutines and both can return a value. Only difference may be the attachment to class. Method sounds more attached to a class but again, people use to call the non attached ones too methods. So, in that aspect too they can be seen as same

Answer (score 2):

In java, and c++, by convention a function is called a method if it is member of a class.

also see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 0):

In many languages methods don't return values while functions do.

Comment: Subroutines which do not return values are called procedures by some. The definition of a method does not specify wether or not a value is returned.