# How to authorize with Test::WWW::Mechanize

Tags: perl, testing, perl-module, www-mechanize

I want to test a .htaccess protected page with Test::WWW::Mechanize but I don't know how can I send credentials for the page? I couldn't find a function that can handle this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
use Test::WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = Test::WWW::Mechanize->new();
my ($user, $pass) = qw/user pass/;
$mech->credentials($user, $pass);
$mech->get_ok('http://example.com');
```

Comment: Is it counted as a test? When we get an agent from Test::WWW::Mechanize, there is no credentials procedure.

Comment: There definitely is. The method is inherited from the superclass WWW::Mechanize. Read a book about Object Orientation if you do not know the difference between method and procedure. - `credentials` is not a TAP emitting method like the various ones named `*_ok` found in Test::WWW::Mechanize.

Comment: @daxim I am totally new to perl so some things are blur but I had already done what I wanted. Anyway, thanks for your answer and [method vs procedure point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036330/method-vs-function-vs-procedure-vs-class)